# More than one instance of activity due to intent

Tags: android, android-intent, instance

For an App I am developing, I override the back button to make it act like the home button so that the state of the main activity is preserved even when the app is exited. Now, I also send a notification to the user from time to time using a service. When this notification is pressed I want to open the main activity again. I noticed though that this creates a second instance of the app, which creates major problems. I am trying to make the main activity go to the front again, without calling oncreate again like so:

**Intent to launch main activity again:**

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
```

This doesn't work though. I still end up with two instances of my main activity. Does anybody know how to fix this?

By the way, I already have `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in my manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a way to force the OS to create only one instance of an activity and thats using the tag launchMode in the Manifest as shown below:

```
<activity android:name="YourActivity" 
  android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
```

Hope this Helps...

Regards

Comment: Turns out this already does the trick and my problem is somewhere else!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this flag to the intent `.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)`, works for me.